# Can't boot slackware after installation. Liloconfig not found

Tags: boot, slackware, lilo

I just installed my first linux distro: slackware.

The installation went fine.
I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DdwZylEQcQ0) for the setup and [this other tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGgAGAle1a8) for formatting the disk.

Unfortunately, slackware won't boot after completing the installation. After some googling I found out that it's most likely due to LILO not working. I've installed LILO using the simple installation, selecting standard and then the MBR option (just like in the first YT video).

After rebooting I'm getting the syslinux boot: menu again. If I reboot without installation USB I'll get the same as prior to installing slackware. Entering liloconfig in the boot: menu as some people online suggested resulted in something like

> liloconfig... no such file or directory found

Can any one of you help me out?

*P.S.- If it matters, I'm installing on a stripped HP Probook 4710s*

Comment: I'm not sure what that particular laptop needs, but it may need `elilo` rather than `lilo`. See the [LILO wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LILO_%28boot_loader%29) for further details. `LILO` used to be the default boot loader for Linux, but the vast majority of Linux installations use `grub` instead. If you use `grub` yourself, then you will probably get a lot more assistance on this forum as it is what other users are familiar with.

Comment: Hmm elilo didn't work. Would you recommend installing grub on top of my current installation? Or is that not possible?

Comment: I'd suggest asking for help over at the official Slackware forums: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/
Lots of folks there have gone through situations similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Using fdisk to create and format partitions instead of cfdisk solved the problem! Apparently LILO doesn't work with cfdisk.

Comment: Great. I didn't realise that Slackware came with `LILO` as its default boot loader, otherwise I wouldn't have suggested `grub` instead. There is good documentation [here](http://docs.slackware.com/slackbook:booting) if you run into any further trouble.

Comment: hmmm... cfdisk shouldn't be a problem for LILO. Glad it's working for you though. Welcome to Slackware!